# Making Maven and module-info work together

Tags: java, maven

I have a project(Java 12) with several Maven dependencies, and now I'm trying to add module-info file like
`module mymodule {
    requires java.net.http;
}`

But if I do this all Maven dependecies (in pom.xml) become invisible for code, and compiler throws errors like `java: package org.openqa.selenium.safari is not visible
  (package org.openqa.selenium.safari is declared in module selenium.safari.driver, but module mymodule does not read it)`

Is it possible to make them work together?

Comment: It will be good if you provide pom.xml here. What is the java version are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

The new module info ist not congruent with the information in the pom.xml. Robert wrote a good article about the differences of both systems:

https://www.sitepoint.com/maven-cannot-generate-module-declaration/